# Why method created at top-level is mentioned in Object.private_methods?

Tags: ruby, self

As I'm understand, method created at top level in Ruby, become private instance method of `Object`. But why `zzz` method name is returned in array when call `Object.private_methods`? And why `Object` and `self` return different private instance methods names?

```
def zzz
   puts 'zzz'
end

p Object.private_instace_methods(false) #[:zzz]
p self.private_methods(false) # [:public, :private, :include, :using, :define_method, :zzz]

p Object.private_methods() #[:inherited, :initialize, :included,..., :zzz,..., :String, :Array, :singleton_method_undefined, :method_missing]
p Object.private_methods(false) #[:inherited, :initialize]

class Temp
  private
  def hello()
    'Hello'
  end
end

p Temp.private_instance_methods(false) # [:hello]
p Temp.new.private_methods(false) # [:hello]

p Temp.private_methods() # [:inherited, :initialize, :included, :extended,...., :zzz,..., :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_removed, :singleton_method_undefined, :method_missing]  
#`zzz` is in list, but there is no `:hello`

p Temp.private_methods(false) # [:inherited, :initialize]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why zzz method name is returned in array when call Object.private_methods?

self at the toplevel is an object called 'main', and 'main' is an instance of class Object:

```
p self
p self.class

--output:--
main
Object
```

The `private_instance_methods()` of a class, e.g. Object, are the `private_methods()` of the instances of the class, e.g. 'main'.

> And why Object and self return different instance methods names?

That can't be because self/main is not a Class, and therefore self/main does not respond to instance_methods():

```
p self.instance_methods

--output:--
1.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `instance_methods' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

As for this:

```
p Object.private_methods(false)

--output:--
[:inherited, :initialize]
```

Object, like all classes, is an instance of Class, so the `private_instance_methods()` of Class:

```
p Class.private_instance_methods(false)

--output:--
[:inherited, :initialize]
```

are the `private_methods()` of the instances of Class, e.g. Object:

```
p Object.private_methods(false)

--output:--
[:inherited, :initialize]
```

And this:

```
Temp.private_methods() # [:inherited, :initialize, :included, :extended,...., :zzz,..., :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_removed, :singleton_method_undefined, :method_missing]  
#`zzz` is in list, but there is no `:hello`
```

zzz() is a method defined in Object, which means that `ALL` objects inherit that method.  Temp is a class, but Temp is also an object(it is an instance of Class):

```
puts Temp.class

--output:--
Class
```

So the Temp object inherits the method zzz() from Object. In fact, ALL objects can call zzz() because all objects inherit from Object, but because zzz is a private instance method in Object, you cannot specify a receiver:

```
def zzz
  puts 'zzz'
end

class Temp
  puts self  #=>Temp
  zzz        #When you don't specify a receiver for a method call
             #ruby uses self, so that line is equivalent to
             #self.zzz, which is equivalent to Temp.zzz

  def hello
    puts 'Hello!'

    puts self  #=>Temp_instance
    zzz        #Same as self.zz, which is equivalent to Temp_instance.zz 
  end
end

--output:--
Temp
zzz
Hello!
#<Temp:0x00000101136238>  
zzz
```

The method hello() can only be called by instances of the class Temp, so Temp can call zzz(), but Temp cannot call hello():

```
class Temp
  def hello
    puts 'Hello!'
  end
end

Temp.new.hello 
Temp.hello

--output:--
Hello!
1.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `hello' for Temp:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: If it's true that private method name of class instance (main) are returned by class object (Object) function `private_methods`, then why it's not true for class Temp. Why it `p Temp.private_methods()` outputs `zzz` but not `hello`. And what about `And why Object and self return different instance methods names?` I meant `private` methods.

Comment: First of all, drop the `private`.  Your questions have nothing to do with the difference between private and public methods.  Second, I have no idea what your comment means, but it seems like you are having problems understanding that a class such as Temp is both a class and an object.  As an object, Temp can call any methods defined by its parent classes, which in order are: `Class, Module, Object, Basic Object`.

Comment: ...On the other hand, defs inside Temp, cannot be called by Temp(unless they look like this: `def self.meth_name ...`.  defs inside Temp can only be called by instances of Temp(or instances of subclasses of Temp).

Comment: Or maybe you don't understand the difference between private_instance_methods() and private_methods().  The first one says, `Okay thing on my left, you are a class(or module), and inside you there are defs, and I will list those defs.`  The second one says, `Okay thing on my left, you are an object, and you can call the methods defined in the class that created you(as well as its superclasses), and I will list those defs.`  That means that only classes(or modules) can call private_instance_methods() because they are the only things that have defs inside them.

Comment: ...On the other hand, ALL objects can call private_methods().

Comment: Thanks for such big explanation. I know about main, that classes in Ruby and are also instances of class Class and difference between instance methods and class methods. But what I don't take in attention, is that Class inherits Object and when I type `Object.private_methods` i talk to Class instance. I maybe should read more about metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are objects. Object is a Class, so it gets Object's instance methods, just like every other object.

Comment: Hm... But why it doesn't work with ordinary classes? I'll update question to make it clearer